# How to use IMPORTXML and SEQUENCE together in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, import, google-sheets-formula, sequence

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B08C1W5N87/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_rvwer?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=avp_only_reviews&sortBy=recent&pageNumber="&SEQUENCE(5,1,1,1))
```

I use the code above to have the links that I would like to scrap the data. There are 5 links.

```
=IMPORTXML(A6,"/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[*]/div/div/div[2]/a[1]/i")
```

I also use the formula above to scrap the data I want from the link. A6 refers to the first link the first  formula creates.

What I would like to do is, if possible, I want to scrap the data from the 5 links and list them in a column.

```
=IMPORTXML(ARRAYFORMULA("https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B08C1W5N87/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_rvwer?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=avp_only_reviews&sortBy=recent&pageNumber="&SEQUENCE(5,1,1,1)),"/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[*]/div/div/div[2]/a[1]/i")
```

The formula above did not work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B08C1W5N87/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_rvwer?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=avp_only_reviews&sortBy=recent&pageNumber="&SEQUENCE(5,1,1,1),"/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[*]/div/div/div[2]/a[1]/i"))
```

The formula above did not work as well. It always scraps the first link's data only.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you share the desired output you want to achieve?

Comment: answer updated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep in mind that IMPORTXML itself is a "type of arrayformula" so it is not supported under ARRAYFORMULA

in your case try to hardcode 5 IMPORTRANGE formulae into array {} like:

```
={IMPORTRANGE(); 
  IMPORTRANGE(); 
  IMPORTRANGE(); 
  etc}
```

---

### update

with new LAMBDA function its possible to do it in one go:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(BYCOL(
 "https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B08C1W5N87/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_rvwer?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=avp_only_reviews&sortBy=recent&pageNumber="&
 SEQUENCE(1,5,1,1), LAMBDA(x, QUERY(IMPORTXML(x, 
 "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[*]/div/div/div[2]/a[1]/i")&"×",,9^9)))), "×"))))
```

[image]